# icons from Devicons not rendering properly in neovim despite I'm using nerd fonts config

Tags: neovim, plugin-nvimtree, plugin-devicons

I'm using nerd fonts in my terminal.

I setup nvimtree with below config -

```
  use {
    'kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua',
    requires = 'kyazdani42/nvim-web-devicons',
    config = function() require'nvim-tree'.setup {} end
  }
```

Below is my nvim tree config -

```
require('nvim-tree').setup({
  disable_netrw = true,
  hijack_netrw = true,
  ignore_ft_on_setup = {'dashboard'},
  open_on_tab = false,
    hijack_cursor = true,
    update_cwd = true,
    update_focused_file = {enable = true, update_cwd = true, ignore_list = {}},
    system_open = {
        -- the command to run this, leaving nil should work in most cases
        cmd = nil,
        -- the command arguments as a list
        args = {}
    },
  view = {
    width = 25,
    side = 'left',
    mappings = { custom_only = false, list = {}}
  },
  git = {
    ignore = true
  },
  renderer = {
    indent_markers = {
      enable = true
    }
  }
})

vim.cmd('nnoremap <space>e :NvimTreeToggle<CR>')

local function open_nvim_tree()
  -- open the tree
  require("nvim-tree.api").tree.open()
end
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "VimEnter" }, { callback = open_nvim_tree })
```

I've configured nerd font in my terminal application.

[image: Iterm text config]

When I open the code in neovim I'm not seeing dev icons

[image: Neovim without icons]

My config is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/nvim/)

Any idea what is wrong with my config and how to fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your version of nvim, I'm using astro neovim

in the /.config/nvim/lua/plugins directory

go into the ui.lua file and set the 3rd line which is a string to

"nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons"

It should look like this
[image]